# Looking for a short story about an immortal

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, immortality

I read the story sometime around 1993, and I seem to remember it being part of some anthology.

The POV character is immortal, in that whenever he is killed, he regenerates.  While he is whole, he doesn't feel anything--taste, pain, etc.  Immediately after he is renewed, he can feel again, but sensation degrades quickly.

As an immortal, he "performs" for individuals in high-society, being killed repeatedly for the amusement of others.  I seem to recall the story taking place immediately after (or during) one such performance.

He's not the only immortal.  He was part of some sort of voyage, and his crew-mates were likewise cursed.

Comment: Given the final paragraph, this sounds like a variant or twist on the ***Flying Dutchman*** story. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Dutchman#In_literature).) That'll probably be useful as a search term to aid anyone who's looking for your story.

Comment: It should be noted that neither the ship, nor its crew, were really focused on in this story, if I recall correctly.  The Flying Dutchman could very well have been an allusion, though.

Comment: Does this story occur on Earth or another planet? Is this set in the past, present or future? You mention "crew", so are they travelling on a boat or spaceship or something else?  When they fight, what type of weapons are used? Are they paid to perform or are they forced to do it? Are they able to regenerate on their own or do they require some external help?

Comment: I don't recall the story ever specifying the planet; I assumed Earth.  Likewise with the voyage: I assumed sea-faring.  I don't recall any fighting, but there was definitely no high-tech (or even contemporary-tech) vibe to the story--it felt like it took place well in the past.

I seem to remember the immortal being paid to be killed, but that may just be my own mind filling in gaps.  The regeneration was completely independent.

Comment: For anyone trawling, the themes of immortal regeneration and sailors match Neal Asher's "Spatterjay" trilogy, although the "performance" and "doesn't feel anything" aspects are not present in that series